# Problem in updating node version for frontend-maven-plugin maven

Tags: node.js, maven, maven-frontend-plugin

***Preface:***

Maven version  : 2.3.2

frontend-maven-plugin version: 0.0.16

Node version : v0.12.9

npmVersion   : 1.4.28

While building Plugin got error 
"**const os = require('os'); Use of const in strict mode.**"

Most of the suggestion i found, to update Node version later than v4.0.0 
But when i am trying to update Node version  my URL is building with X64,
*****http://nodejs.org/dist/v4.0.0/***x64***/node.exe*****

But it should be http://nodejs.org/dist/v4.0.0/***win-x64***/node.exe

I tried with including  **nodeDownloadRoot** tag but no luck.

plugin maven is below

```
 <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.0.16</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <workingDirectory>src/main/node</workingDirectory>
                    </configuration>

                    <executions>

                        <execution>
                            <id>install node and npm</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <nodeVersion>v0.12.9</nodeVersion>
                                <npmVersion>1.4.28</npmVersion>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>

                        <execution>
                            <id>npm install</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>npm</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <!-- Optional configuration which provides for running any npm command -->
                            <configuration>
                                <arguments>install</arguments>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>

                        <execution>
                            <id>grunt build</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>grunt</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <!-- optional: the default phase is "generate-resources" -->
                            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>npm install production</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>npm</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <!-- Optional configuration which provides for running any npm command -->
                            <configuration>
                                <arguments>install --production --prefix ../build</arguments>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

Any help will me much appreciated.